# Only my first CSS media size queries are working

Tags: css

Got a frustrating issue, that if I add more than one set of media queries they will not display.

Only the "top" media query is displaying (768 to 1040)

If I add any more they will not activate, I have tried the 320px CSS media queries on their own and they work fine.

```
 @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 475px){ .....
```

Comment: NO HTML in the fiddle? Try reducing the CSS you *have* provided to just enough to demo the issue.

Comment: Perhaps if you remove all the extra clutter from your CSS and start with something more simple with an HTML element that shows your problem in action, it will be easier for others to understand your problem. You may even find the solution yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few errors in the provided CSS, if you look on lines 786, 1048 and 1295 you'll see:

```
.tab-description .tab-content table [ /* <<------- */
    width:100%!important;
    height:100%!important;
}
```

Here you will find a square bracket instead of the expected `{` which is causing everything below this line to stop working.

On lines 140, 400, 664, 926 & 1187 you'll find:

```
visibility: hidden;
```

without it being encapsulated by any selector, which isn't somehting CSS likes.

On line 178, 440, 702, 964 & 1220 there's this:

```
.cart-info tbody .quantity text { /* <<------ */
    width: 23px;
}
```

The `text` selector isn't a selector at all, I'm assuming you either meant to use `.text` or `#text'

Hope this helps!

Comment: Haha, was about to answer :')

Comment: @MHakvoort Wasn't a hard one to spot this time. some typo's aren't as easy to spot

Comment: True, haha. And the fact that it's friday will not make it easier I guess ;-)

Comment: @MHakvoort definetly not, I found some more just now